# Converting a context free grammar into a LL(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, ll-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
S -> S+S|SS|S*|(S)|a
```

How do I convert it into a LL(1) grammar?

I tried to eliminate left recursion so I got

```
S->(S)S'|aS'
S'->+SS'|SS'|*S'|epsilon
```

I also tried to do left factoring first and then eliminate left recursion and I got something like :

```
S->(S)S"|aS"
       S"->S'S"|epsilon
       S'->+S|*|S
```

But I still do not get a perfect answer. I feel grammar is still not LL(1). Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be theoretical rather than practical. (The grammar does not appear to be realistic.) Try http://cs.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @RaymondChen: It's a (simplified) grammar for regular expressions using `+` for the alternation operator usually written as `|`. Why is that not realistic?

Comment: @rici Most languages have more terminals than `a`. If you want a regular expression parser, then just use an existing one - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how is the second grammar not already LL(1)?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to try writing the grammar so that you read some complete term, then optionally try extending it in some way. For example, you might try something like this:

> S → Term
>
> Term → CoreTerm OptMore
>
> CoreTerm → a | (Term)
>
> OptMore → ε | Term | + Term | * OptMore

For example, you'd derive a(a+a)*a as

> S
>
> ⇒ Term
>
> ⇒ CoreTerm OptMore
>
> ⇒ a OptMore
>
> ⇒ a Term
>
> ⇒ a CoreTerm OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(CoreTerm OptMore) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a OptMore) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + Term) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + CoreTerm OptMore) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a OptMore) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a) OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a)* OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a)* Term
>
> ⇒ a(a + a)* CoreTerm OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a)* a OptMore
>
> ⇒ a(a + a)* a

To see that this is an LL(1) grammar, here's the FIRST sets:

- FIRST(S) = {
- FIRST(Term) = { a, ( }
- FIRST(CoreTerm) = { a, ( }
- FIRST(OptMore) = { ε, a, (, +, * }

Here's the FOLLOW sets:

- FOLLOW(S) = {$}
- FOLLOW(Term) = {$, )}
- FOLLOW(CoreTerm) = {a, (, +, *, $}
- FOLLOW(OptMore) = {$, )}

So now we can fill in the parse table:

```
         | a                | (                | +      | *         | )   | $
---------+------------------+------------------+--------+-----------+-----+------
S        | Term             | Term             |        |           |     |
Term     | CoreTerm OptMore | CoreTerm OptMore |        |           |     |
CoreTerm | a                | (Term)           |        |           |     |
OptMore  | Term             | Term             | + Term | * OptMore | eps | eps
```

So this grammar is indeed LL(1).